# Does Google App Engine allows admin address to be used as sender?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendmail

Trying sending mail from Google App Engine in python using mail.send_mail
It gives me error saying UnAuthorized Sender, even when I am using admin address as the sender's email.
Does GAE allows that?

Comment: did you add your email address to Authorized email senders list?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks. It took me too long to find out where can I add email senders list.

Comment: yeah, it's too hard for the first timers.. console -> app engine -> settings